# VBA to find the last 5 rows in a column and concatenate the text into cell I2, seperated by ","

Tags: excel, vba, row, concatenation

Hi All i am trying to write a code that looks for the Last Row in a column "G" and then Concatenates the Last 5 rows seperated by a "," into cell "I2".

I know how to Concatenate 5 specific Cells, and to find the last Row etc but i can't work out how to join them together.

Any Help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what code you have currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Join Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) will concatenate a delimited string but the range of rows needs to be flipped with [TRANSPOSE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) first.

```
Dim ws7 As Worksheet

Set ws7 = Worksheets("sheet7")
With ws7
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)
        With .Resize(5, 1).Offset(-4, 0)
            ws7.Cells(2, 9) = _
                Join(Application.Transpose(.Cells.Value2), Chr(44))
        End With
    End With
End With
```

Comment: HI Jeeped, Thank youfor taking the time to look at this, i forgot to say that the Cells in Column "G" have formulas in them and i would like the value of the Formula to be, at the moment i get Value Error.

Comment: Don't know why you would be getting that error; the default for a [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) is the same as a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx); that being the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx). I've tested this both with the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) and without on formulas and there doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Still get Value Error, In each cell in G the Value from the Formula is a Single Letter and NOT a number.

Comment: Function Copylast5() As Integer
    Dim ws7 As Worksheet
    Set ws7 = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
    With ws7
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)
        With .Resize(5, 1).Offset(-4, 0)
            ws7.Cells(2, 9) = _
                Join(Application.Transpose(.Cells.Value2), Chr(44))
        End With
    End With
    End With
    End Function